# c# window application system.data.oledb.oledbexception operation must use an updateable query

Tags: c#, oledbexception

I have made a window application that works very well when i ran through but after creating its setup it is throwing below mentioned exception. I have try to give full access to the database file but still it is not working.

> system.data.oledb.oledbexception operation must use an updateable.
>   query

i am using window 7 and installation folder is c:\program files\abc\ and access db is in same folder. Is this any issue of permissions? Please assist me to remove this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be some permission issue just refer [this Link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/74/Solving-the-Operation-Must-Use-An-Updateable-Query-error)

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/74/Solving-the-Operation-Must-Use-An-Updateable-Query-error

Make sure the ASPNET account (or whatever account is in use at the time) has
Change permissions to the directory where the .mdb file is located. Access
needs to write some temp and locking files during the operation.

Comment: Thanks,bro..later i was granting permission to database file, but now i have tried to give permission to folder and it works..Thanks.

Comment: now here is one more question that how can i automatically give permission to this folder on the time of installation